# A "<br />" is on the loose in the "We already handled all the flags on this post" popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools, error-message

> [image]

So yeah, in the popup:

> Thanks we've already handled all the flags on this post. If you wish to flag it anyway, please navigate to the post

... there's a random `<br />`.

<sup>But you knew that already, because you can see it in the screenshot.</sup>

Comment: -1 because your lasso missed

Comment: +1 for free hand (though not red) lasso.

Comment: Looks like simple case of using `.text()` instead of `.html()`. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Red lasso fails over a red-popup :(.

Comment: @Matt Related feature request [stop having red popups, they ruin freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland)

Comment: fix `<i>ncomming</i>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `<pre>2013.12.2.1700</pre>` for meta and `<pre>2013.12.2.1187</pre>` for sites.

Comment: <i>N</i>ice&#33;